# Symfony requestStack->getCurrentRequest() returning empty post array

Tags: event-listener, symfony-3.4

Trying to get POST parameters in doctrine listener. But, getting an empty array. Tried to push the request to requeststack in controller as well. But, still coming in as empty.

```
class OrderListener
{
    private $requestStack;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
    }

    public function postPersist(LifecycleEventArgs $args)
    {
        $entity = $this->getObject();
        if ($entity instanceof Order) {
            $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();

            $this->handleEvent($entity, $args->getEntityManager());
        }
    }

    public function handleEvent(Order $order, EntityManagerInterface $em)
    {
       // here $request->request->all() is empty
       $request = $this->requestStack->getCurrentRequest();
       $transaction = new Transaction();
       $transaction->setOrder($order);
       $transaction->setRemoteId($request->request->get('stripeInvoiceId'));
       ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, `json_decode($request->getContent(), true)` gave me the correct params. Returned an array of post data. Strange thing is `$request->request->all()` should have worked too.